# UIViewController completely out of place on the screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am putting together a sample iPhone app for practice.  It is a drill-down interface with doctors who have patients who have prescriptions and visits using Core Data and a story board.

Everything was going great until I started on the Edit/View doctor screen.  Because this screen is triggered by a button in the UITableViewCell, it seemed that there was no way to create a segue on the story board to an edit/view screen because the buttons in the cells are dynamically created.

I decided to make a separate UIViewController custom class and I let Xcode generate the XIB for me to make sure I did not mess up anything.  I presented the edit/view view controller by pushing onto the navigation controller.  The problem is that the contents of the edit/view screen were nearly completely off the screen.  With my first attempt, a navigation bar I put at the top appeared at the very bottom of the screen in the simulator with all of the rest of the text fields and labels not showing at all.

I then created another view controller with xib, specifying iPhone only and simply put a label with "Hello" in the center of the view.  When I ran the simulator, "Hello" was centered vertically, but was all the way to the right of the screen with only "He" showing.  I tried played with anything I could find to play with, but nothing fixes it.  I am not trying to do anything unusual.  I want to do everything in the usual accepted way.

Also, it seems like Interface Builder makes the views look like big square iPad screens even when I have specified iPhone.  I did check the frame dimensions and it was wxh = 600x600.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me to search for 600x600 and it seems that this is the new UIView that Interface Builder provides by default.  Because there are many screen sizes, Constraints are apparently mandatory now.

My edit/view form was completely fixed by viewing the XIB and going to:

Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Add Missing Constraints.